# Controlling the ShareThis javascript window opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharethis

I have just started using [ShareThis Widget](http://www.sharethis.com/) to help handle social media integration with one of our sites. While the functionality is great, I feel I lose a lot of the capabilities I have if I were to code each item by hand, such as the ability to control the size of the windows opened by clicking a 'share' functionality.

While their site shows basic functions you can add to the buttons (url, etc) I am looking to customize the feel such that when a button is clicked, I can control the size of that window or even possibly open in an existing colorbox snippet.

Has anybody had luck with this before? When I try to control via javascript function it just seems to get overwritten or ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your question is resolved, but you will need to add as following inside JS.

```
popup: 'true'
```

The same is on their [Support Page](http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475019-open-widget-in-new-window-)

Comment: thanks. their source has since been updated from 9/2011. We no longer use the software but good information for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to unbind their events and handle them all yourself. It probably isn't a good idea, as your code will be at the mercy of their implementation.